# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUserRoles'

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am making websites where I need roles such as admin, Doctor , patient ,Receptionist.

I want to store UserId and roleid in AspNetUserRoles table.It is working longest I dont add duplicate data . But once I add duplicate data it gives me error.

I want different users can have one roles within Admin, Doctor, Patient ,or Receptionist. But I cannot add role more than one time in table.
Please can anyone give me suggestion and help with this issue ?

This is AspNetUserRoles table and error

[image]

Comment: Where is you DDL?

Comment: please provide details about your schema and sample data *in text*, not as images; as text, it makes it *much easier* for others to see what is going on, and to recreate your scenario as part of providing help

Comment: Does the _User_ has only one (1) _Role_ or can have many _Roles_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have RoleId as a Primary Key(PK). You cannot have duplicate values that are a primary key. RoleId needs to be a Foreign key(FK) that relates to a table that contains your roles.

Comment: Thanks. Now i can add duplicate data to RoleId Column.